# how to mark a message as persistent using spring-rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

This is how I'm creating an exchange and binding a queue to it

```
<rabbit:topic-exchange id="dataExchange" name="MQ-EXCHANGE" durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="COMM_QUEUE" pattern="queue.*" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

I have read a lot of posts on the Internet where it is written that a message is also needed to be marked persistent if it is to be secured in case rabbitmq or the queue crashes. But I couldn't figure out how to mark my messages persistent.

This is how I'm publishing the messages to the queue

```
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void produceMessage(Object message, String routingKey) {
        template.convertAndSend(routingKey, message);  
    }
```

I looked for different API methods to know this and also tried to look for any specific property that I could configure in the XML but couldn't find a way. Any guidance ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default delivery mode (in `MessageProperties`) **is** `PERSISTENT`. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/core/MessageProperties.java#L60).

To make it non-persistent you need to use a `convertAndSend(...)` method with a `MessagePostProcessor` to set the deliveryMode property.